# Is it possible to remove </br> tag that is showing in tooltip of ngx-data table?

Tags: angular, ngx-datatable

I have used  with  tag. it is working fine, but the tooltip is showing  tag. Can we remove  tag in tooltip?
please refer screenshot and example.
[image]

[enter link description here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular5-ngx-datatable-3frssp?file=app%2Fngxtable%2Fngxtable.component.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```html
   

>  <ngx-datatable-column name="Name</br> Phone Number" prop="name"
> [width]="200">
>               <ng-template ngx-datatable-header-template let-column="column">
>                 <span title="Name,Phone Number">NAME <br /> PHONE NUMBER</span>
>               </ng-template>
>     </ngx-datable-column>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes it's possible, I checked in your code, please goto line number **17 or 18**, and update the value of name attribute from this `name="Name </br> FullName"` to `name="Name FullName"`

[image]

Comment: No I want to use both example name </br> Phone number </br> Email, I would like to use this format. Actually it displays correctly, but tooltip shows "  name </br> Phone number </br> Email". I want to remove <"/br>" showing in tooltip

Comment: Yes, I know but it will update only tooltip

Comment: yeah, could you provide the answer please.

Comment: I edit my answer, also attached the screenshot